# Export symbols of C++ class with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using dlopen to merge symbols of a dynamically loaded library and its host, and in the host I have a class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {/* ... */}
    void bar() {/* ... */}
};

int main() {
    // Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this with `g++ -Wl,--export-dynamic -o test test.cpp` and inspecting the symbols with `nm -g test`.
I expect the symbols `_ZN3FooC1Ev` and `_ZN3FooC2Ev` to exist in the executable, since the dynamic library needs them, but they do not appear unless I use them by un-commenting the above line. I believe it is being optimized out, since GCC thinks it is not needed.

How do I force the constructor and methods of Foo to be included in the host binary?

Comment: I can't get `_ZN3FooC1Ev` and `_ZN3FooC2Ev` even when specifying `-O0`... Weird

Comment: If you compile just the class without `main` into a separate object file do you get the symbols you would expect?  Or if you only compile (`-c`) and don't link?

Comment: Hmm, just tried compiling without linking, still missing the symbols.  Even when I add a static member it's still absent.

Comment: gcc would do different for .so and executable file to useless symbols, there's a gcc option, but i forgot exactly what is it. For .so, default would export the symbols, but for executable file, default is removing the useless symbols.

Comment: A class definition with inlined method definitions do not generate any symbol if you don't define any object. Don't define the methods as inlined...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I think this is the answer. (Feel free to write it as an answer so I can accept it.) Expanding my example class into separate declaration and implementation gives me the symbols I need in the executable. This is interesting because I thought defining methods "inline" as you say was syntactically the same as a declaration and implementation, but I suppose it tells the compiler to actually inline the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class definition with inlined method definitions do not generate any symbol if you don't, at least, define an object.
So don't define the methods as inlined if you want to ensure their visibility...

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate dynamicaly loaded libraries you habe to  build it with:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o lib1.so lib1.c
```

**-fPIC** is used to tell GCC to produce Position Independent Code.
-**shared** is used to indicate it’s a shared object

To link against your library test.so you can use the following:

```
$ gcc -L$(pwd) -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd) --enable-new-dtags -o test main.c -l1 -l2
```

With **-rpath=/my/location** you tell the linker the list of alternate locations
To verify the dynamic section of your binary  you can use:`$ readelf -d test`